# how to add a foreign key to sequelize model

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

i need to add foreign key to the users table that references the id of the gym,
what is the right syntax?

```
export class User extends Model<User> {
// user properties:
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  public id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public first_name: string;

  // here i need to reference the gym_id to the id from the gym table:

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
 // @ForeignKey(Gym.id)
  public gym_id: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of association:
Please check this document: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#model-association

If it's one-to-many then just like this:

```
  @ForeignKey(() => Gym)
  @Column
  gym_id: number

  @BelongsTo(() => Gym)
  gym: Gym
```